# run Javascript after replacing location

Tags: javascript, html

Let say 
B.html contains:

```
First name: <input type="text" name="fname">
```

i want to make an anchor link in page a.html and fill this text field.

i tried in A.html:

```
<a href="javascript:window.location.replace('b.html');document.getElementsByName('fname')[0].value='test';"> go to B </a>
```

But it loads in the same page and wont load in second page.
any idea?
thanks.

Comment: Why don't u just make a link?

Comment: anyway need to run javaScript on second page from first page

Comment: My instinctive answer would be that you can't run arbitrary JS from one page inside another totally different one, because... well, obvious security reasons (steal your credit card number, stuff like that) but I may be wrong

Comment: its possible , depend on page security , but i need to run script after loading second page or add the script end of next page lines , but i dont know how?

Comment: You wont be able to achieve your goal this way. You have to pass values by querystring, localstorage, postmessage, using iframe, whatever, to access those.

Comment: @Lain , let say i have no access in second page source to check query string ?
i just need to fill textbox. any Idea?

Comment: If you can not alter page B and it does not allow you to fill in any values with predefined parameters as well as CO is given, you wont be able to achieve it using JS.

Comment: in JavaScript is possible, the second page need to protect java script injection which i disabled. but i dont know how?

Comment: Well, let me know once you find out.